# In C#, is there any more elegant way to take a DateTime and calculate how many months until the "next" Quarter?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want a function in C#, where I

1. Take a date and get the month
2. Determine how many months until the next quarter of the year BUT if the number is 1, then it looks to get the number to the following quarter (basically adds 3 to it)

Here are some examples:

1. If the current date is in the month of Jan, I want the function to return 3. (as Apr would be the first month of the next quarter)
2. If its Feb i would want it to return 2;
3. If its March then I would return 4 (as it would be 1 but then 3 is added to get to the next quarter)

right now i literally have a switch statement with 12 cases (from 1 to 12) which works but i was looking to see if there was a more elegant way to write this function

Comment: Save somewhere the beginning of a quarter month, then find the closest one (loop!).

Comment: i don't quite understand why you would return 4 for march, since the next quarter will start in april. Also february should return only 1 since it is only march until the next quarter

Comment: @zahorak Requirement 2 in the question clearly says that if one month is remaining, it should return the number of months until the quarter after next.

Comment: @zahorak - Feb would return 2 as there are 2 months left in current quarter (Feb and March).  March returns 4 because if there is only one month left i want to skip to the following quarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int untilNextQuarter = 4 - (currentMonth % 3);
```

Or a slightly clearer but slightly less efficient approach:

```
int[] remainingMonths = new[] { 3, 2, 4 };
int untilNextQuarter = remainingMonths[(currentMonth - 1) % 3];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime.Now.Month
```

Returns the month number.

Just use simple if-else:

```
public int GetMonthsToQuater(){
    if(1<date.Month<3)
        return 4-date.Month;
    else...
}
```